# Internet Explorer 9 tab freezes often

Tags: freeze, internet-explorer-9

My Internet Explorer 9 freezes very often while other tabs are working well.

Neither Refresh (<kbd>F5</kbd>) nor Stop (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) works.

What I can do is just killing the tab.

I think it happens way too often though my laptop is quite new (Windows 7, Ivy-Bridge i5, 6GB RAM).

What is the reason and how I could fix or prevent it?

Comment: `how I could fix or prevent it?` I would recommend using any other proper browser.

Comment: Is it always the same site? Is it caused by a plugin? There is insufficient information in this question to provide an answer.

Comment: Try a reset of IE9...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Reset-Internet-Explorer-settings-in-Internet-Explorer-9